# Is there a way for me add a text right after the title in donut chart?

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm using nvd3js for angular (http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/), and I would like to add a text right after the title (in this case the title is 98%) and the text to be added is "done". I was able to make it work so far, but I couldn't seem to make it work. This is my plunkr so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/KSdnFepUaI4MUCwAQJgP?p=preview

```
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            donut: true,
            x: function(d){return d.key;},
            y: function(d){return d.y;},
            showLabels: false,
            showLegend: false,
            title: '89%',
            transitionDuration: 500,
            tooltips: false,
            donutRatio: 1
        }
```

---

```
<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

<style>
  .nv-pie-title {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 95px !important;
    fill: #cccccc !important;
 }
</style>
```